# undefined is not a function (near '....data.map....') |React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, api, geolocation

I am new to React native and trying to destructure the json response which i have got from my API call using the map function and somehow it is giving me the above error. I want to display the aqi and dominant pollutants using a text componenet. I am using the AQICN API.

```
import React,{ useState , useEffect} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View ,ActivityIndicator, ScrollView,FlatList} from 'react-native';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';


export default function HomeScreen({navigation}) {

  const [location, setLocation] = useState(null);
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(null);
  //Lat and Long

  const [latitude, setLatitude] = useState(null);
  const [longitude , setLongitude]= useState(null);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const [loader, setLoader]=useState(true);


  useEffect(() => {
    (
      async () => {
      let { status } = await Location.requestPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        setErrorMsg('Permission Denied');
        return;
      }

      let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
      setLocation(location);
      //Changes
      setLatitude(location.coords.latitude);
      setLongitude(location.coords.longitude);

      const la=latitude;
      const lo=longitude;
      
      async function AqicnApiCall() {
        
          let res = await fetch("https://api.waqi.info/feed/geo:"+ latitude +";"+ longitude +"/?token=ac3a71fc80931abd95ede14c2040f0678f578703")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((json) => setData(json.data))
        .catch((error) =>console.log(error))
         
        }    
        
        AqicnApiCall();
            
    })();
  }, [latitude, longitude]);


    //const obj=JSON.stringify(data);
    
    


    return (
    <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
        
        {
          data.map((d) =>{
            console.log(d);
            return(
              <Text style={styles.container}>{d.data.aqi}</Text>
            )
          })
        }
    </ScrollView>
  );
}





   const styles= StyleSheet.create({
     container: {
       padding:20,
       marginTop:15,
       margin:10,

     },
     paragraph : {
       padding:20,
       marginTop:5,
     }


   });
```

This is the API response, i need the dominant pollutant and aqi.

[image]

Comment: Is data an array or an object? Seems to be an object. Am I wrong?

Comment: My bad. Its an object. Can you please guide me ?
I tried other ways its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working App: [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/de485b)

[image]

Access `aqi` and `dominentpol` like below:

```js
 return (
    <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.container}>AQI: {data?.aqi}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.container}>
        Dominant Pollutant: {data?.dominentpol}
      </Text>
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```

Full Working code:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ActivityIndicator,
  ScrollView,
  FlatList,
} from 'react-native';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';

export default function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState(null);
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(null);
  //Lat and Long

  const [latitude, setLatitude] = useState(null);
  const [longitude, setLongitude] = useState(null);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const [loader, setLoader] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      let { status } = await Location.requestPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        setErrorMsg('Permission Denied');
        return;
      }

      let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
      setLocation(location);
      //Changes
      setLatitude(location.coords.latitude);
      setLongitude(location.coords.longitude);

      const la = latitude;
      const lo = longitude;

      async function AqicnApiCall() {
        let res = await fetch(
          'https://api.waqi.info/feed/geo:' +
            latitude +
            ';' +
            longitude +
            '/?token=ac3a71fc80931abd95ede14c2040f0678f578703'
        )
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((json) => {
            console.log('data: ', json.data);
            setData(json.data);
          })
          .catch((error) => console.log(error));
      }

      AqicnApiCall();
    })();
  }, [latitude, longitude]);

  //const obj=JSON.stringify(data);

  return (
    <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.container}>AQI: {data?.aqi}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.container}>
        Dominant Pollutant: {data?.dominentpol}
      </Text>
    </ScrollView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    padding: 20,
    marginTop: 15,
    margin: 10,
  },
  paragraph: {
    padding: 20,
    marginTop: 5,
  },
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much ketan. Can you please help me on another thing?
The api is also returning iqai which contains the pollutant names with their values, I was trying to access it using the map function but its not working. Can you  please help?

Comment: May I know why the answer is downvoted even after solving the problem mentioned by the OP?

Comment: Didn't understand that. I have accepted the answer and the code is working .

Answer (score 0):

As data isn't an array, and I see that you just want to display `aqi` value,

```
<ScrollView style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={styles.container}>{data?.aqi}</Text>
</ScrollView>
```

On the screenshot, it seems that you can only iterate on `data.attributions`.

```
<ScrollView style={styles.container}>
    {data.attributions.map(attr => <Text>{attr.something}</Text>}
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: data ?.aqi is working fine.
But for map function is giving 
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.iaqi.map') error.

Comment: yes because again `data.iaqi` is not an array but an object

Answer (score -1):

I think some of d.data is undefined or null. Please try this.

```
<ScrollView style={styles.container}>
    
    {
      data && data.map((d) =>{
        console.log(d);
        return(
          <Text style={styles.container}>{d?.data?.aqi}</Text>
        )
      })
    }
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Didnt work . Sorry for mentioning late the data is json object not array.